# MSSQL: Priority level of Delete Cascade vs FOR Delete Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, foreign-keys

I would like to know what happens when a row in a parent table is deleted. That is, what would happen next, will `TRIGGER FOR DELETE` be executed or `Delete Cascade` ?

Predicament: Trigger needs to get data from child table but if `Delete Cascade` is executed before the trigger, there would be no data to work with in the `Delete trigger`.

In short which of these two is correct:

`ROW DELETED -> DELETE CASCADE LOGIC -> FOR DELETE TRIGGER LOGIC`
OR

`ROW DELETED -> FOR DELETE TRIGGER LOGIC -> DELETE CASCADE LOGIC`

Answer (score 0):

The trigger fires after the rows are deleted. So the child rows will be gone as well. If this is not going to work for you, you might want to consider an Instead Of trigger so you can control things a bit better. You can read more about them [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179288(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: I think Insted Of trigger would not work with Foreign key delete cascade. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191208(v=sql.105).aspx